# How to find difference between two forks via github web interface?

Tags: git, github, diff

Is it possible to find difference between fork and master via github web interface? e.i. I want to know what's new in fork relative to master.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can compare repositories as described here:  https://github.com/blog/683-cross-repository-compare-view

The key part is using the `<user>:` prefix to identify the owner of another fork on the same network.